# Removing an object from a mutable dictionary throws an exception

Tags: ios, cocoa, nsdictionary

I'm getting an exception after attempting to remove an object from a NSMutableDictionary. The relevant code follows. The 'settings' is passed to the method and can be a NSDictionary or a NSMutableDictionary.

```
 NSMutableDictionary *mutableSettings = nil;
 if ([settings isKindOfClass:[NSMutableDictionary class]])
     mutableSettings = (NSMutableDictionary *)settings;
 else 
     mutableSettings = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:settings] autorelease];

 [mutableSettings removeObjectForKey:@"akey"];
```

This crashes with

> > *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary removeObjectForKey:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'

Whats wrong with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem here is that both `NSDictionary` and `NSMutableDictionary` return `__NSCFDictionary` as their `class`, due to the fact that `NSDictionary` is a class cluster.

I think you will just have to make a mutable copy of the `settings` dictionary whether it is mutable or not.

```
NSMutableDictionary *mutableSettings = [settings mutableCopy];
```

Comment: Also, as the underscores imply, `__NSCFDictionary` is a private class. It isn't necessarily the only dictionary class, and it's not guaranteed to be around forever. More relevantly, it's a subclass of NSMutableDictionary, so *every* dictionary (that is an instance of `__NSCFDictionary`) is a kind of NSMutableDictionary. All of these things mean that there is no reliable way to tell whether a dictionary—or any other plist object—is mutable or not.